# select query for date between

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a project where i have to fetch data of between dates plus the name of user.
The query for only `date between`is working fine but with `and` operater its going in wrong way so please suggest me how to implement it to achieve desired output.
this is my code:

```
$qry11=mysqli_query($con,"select * from entry where (create_date between '$first' and '$second') && cnor='$nme'");
```

so please suggest ne how to do this....any idea will be appreciate with highly gratitude.

Comment: I think you need to replace the `&&` by `AND`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&&
```

should be replaced with

```
AND
```

You seem to be already using `AND` in your query right

```
(create_date between '$first' and '$second')
```

Comment: not working............

Comment: Check the console for any potential errors

Answer (score 0):

use the query like below

```
$qry11=mysqli_query($con,"select * from entry where (create_date between '$first' and '$second') and cnor='$nme'");
```

Comment: not working...........

Comment: will You please describe cnor='$nme' this part? what You want to pick up in this condition?